# Segmentation fault in 2D array unsigned char using calloc in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, unsigned, calloc

I've trying to allocate an `unsigned char**` using **calloc**:

```
newmatriz = (unsigned char**) calloc(width, sizeof(unsigned char));

for (j=0 ; j < width; j++)
{
    if (newmatriz[j]=(unsigned char*)calloc(witdh, sizeof(unsigned char)) == NULL){
        printf("Memory allocation error. Exit program\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

for (i=0;i<width;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<width;j++)
    {
        newmatriz[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

But I get segmentation fault when I'm trying to acces the pos [i][j]

Is problem be related to the use int as iterator?

Comment: should be `newmatriz=calloc(width, sizeof(unsigned char*))`

Comment: Do **not** cast `void *` as returned by `calloc()`&friends. Also: do not use `sizeof(char)` (signed/unsigned the same). That will never be different than 1, as that's what is is explicitly defined to yield by the standard.

Comment: The code is missing an asterisk (see BLUEPIXY's comment). Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: I removed the cast from calloc, still getting the same error in fact, I get this warning when compiling:
filtrodefinitivo.c:298:29: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
             if (newmatriz[j]=calloc(width, sizeof(unsigned char)) == NULL){

Comment: @user3055867, that's a good reason not to explicitly cast the return value of `malloc` family of functions. You were hiding a problem by using explicit cast.

Comment: It's already included.

Comment: ... and if it's not the typo that causes the error it might very well be the missing include. Btw.: Have you edited your question because you haven't had the typo in the original code? The problem is, that the answers now don't make sense anymore

Comment: `if (newmatriz[j]=calloc(width, sizeof(unsigned char)) == NULL){` shoud be `if ((newmatriz[j]=calloc(width, sizeof(unsigned char))) == NULL){ `

Comment: I did rollback on the code, sorry. And thanks to all, was a brackets problem! Neverminded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in this statement. Instead of `sizeof( unsigned char )` you have to use `sizeof( unsigned char * )`

```
newmatriz = (unsigned char**) calloc(width, sizeof(unsigned char *));
                                                            ^^^^^^
```

Also this if statement is incorrect

```
if ( newmatriz[j] = calloc(witdh, sizeof(unsigned char) ) == NULL){
```

In this statement `newmatriz[j]` is set either to 1 or 0 depending on whether the memory allocation was successfull or not.

I think you mean

```
if ( ( newmatriz[j] = calloc(witdh, sizeof(unsigned char) ) ) == NULL){
```

And these loops

```
for (i=0;i<width;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<width;j++)
    {
        newmatriz[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

do not make sense because `calloc` already initialized the allocated memory by zeroes.

Comment: Hi, the pointer was fixing, the loops are just for checking the access to the matrix, but I get segmentation fault.

Comment: @user3055867 See my updated post. Next time please try to copy and paste at least a compiled example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks!! That was the error!! Now it compiles with no warnings and seems to work !

Comment: @user3055867 You should always pay attention to warnings.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple newmatriz is an array (aka pointer) to unsigned char* you are allocation unsigned char simply change the top line to allocate the correctly sized array, in this case you want an array of byte size `width*sizeof(unsigned char*)` not `width*sizeof(unsigned char)` as you currently have it.

```
newmatriz = (unsigned char**) calloc(width, sizeof(unsigned char*));
for (j=0 ; j < width; j++){
    if (newmatriz[j]=(unsigned char*)calloc(witdh, sizeof(unsigned char)) == NULL){
       printf("Memory allocation error. Exit program\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have also tried that before and now but still doesn't working.

Comment: Should work so long as you don't run out of memory, which you are testing for.

Answer (score 0):

In the second `calloc()` there are some brackets missing:

```
if (newmatriz[j] = calloc(witdh, sizeof(unsigned char)) == NULL){
```

should be

```
if ((newmatriz[j] = calloc(witdh, sizeof(unsigned char))) == NULL){
```

Without that, `calloc()`s result is compared with NULL and the result of the comparison instead of the pointer is stored in `newmatriz[j]`